# Can someone explain how to properly write this Javascript program?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for someone to show me how this task should be done and where I went wrong. The instructions are as follows:

"Write your code for this exercise in this file beneath this long comment.
Please be certain to use only syntax and techniques covered in the assigned
freeCodeCamp courses.

(The material referenced here was the 110 lessons of FreeCodeCamp's basic Javascript, exploring Var and Let keywords and the 26 Object oriented programming lessons)

1. Write a function named createMovie that expects to receive three arguments:
   title, duration, and quote. This function should return an object. The object
   it returns should have properties that are also named title, duration, and
   quote. The values assigned to these properties should be the values that are
   passed to the function. Additionally, the object that createMovie returns
   should have two methods:

   isLongerThan - a function that accepts one movie object as a parameter and
     returns true if the movie is longer than the one that is passed to it as
     an argument and false otherwise.

   logQuote - a function that logs the value of the movie object's quote
       property to the console.
2. Create a variable named movies and assign to it an array. This array should
   contain six objects that are created by calling the createMovie function. The
   values you should pass to the createMovie function to create these objects are:

```
title              | duration | line
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Star Wars          |   121    | If there's a bright center to the universe,
                   |          | you're on the planet that it's farthest from.
                   |          |
Pulp Fiction       |   154    | Do you know what they call a Quarter Pounder
                   |          | with Cheese in France?
                   |          |
Dirty Dancing      |   100    | Nobody puts Baby in a corner.
                   |          |
Forrest Gump       |   142    | Life is like a box of chocolates.
                   |          |
The Wizard of Oz   |   101    | Lions and tigers and bears, oh my!
                   |          |
Cabaret            |   124    | Life is a cabaret, old chum, so come to the
                   |          | cabaret.
```

3. Write the following two functions, both of which use the movies array to
   determine what to return.

   getMovieByTitle - this function expects a string as a parameter and
       returns the object in the movies array whose title property is equal to
       the string that is passed to it (if there is one).

   getAverageDuration - this function returns the average duration of all the
       movies in the array.

You can test your code by opening index.html in Chrome and using the console
(see http://jsforcats.com/ for instructions on using the console). After you
correct any errors you see when you open the console, you can run commands such
as those below and verify the output.

var starWars = getMovieByTitle('Star Wars');

var pulpFiction = getMovieByTitle('Pulp Fiction');

pulpFiction.isLongerThan(starWars);

pulpFiction.logQuote();

getAverageDuration();
*/"

so the code I wrote was formed from some pseudo-code that was as best as I could get towards the answer.
I'm completely new to this and I've definitely bitten off more than I can chew. Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is as far as I got:

```
var Movies = [];

function CreateMovie (id, title, duration, quote) {

  let Films = {
    title: title,
    duration: duration,
    quote: quote,
    isLongerThan: function (Movies) {
      for (var x = 0; x < Movies.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < Movies[x].length; y++) {
      if (This.duration > Movies[x][y].duration) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
            }
          }
        }
      },
    logQuote: function (title){
      for (var x = 0; x < Movies.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < Movies[x].length; y++){
      if (Movies[x][y].hasOwnProperty(title)){
        console.log(Movies[x][y].quote)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  Movies.push(Films);

  return Films;
};

function getMovieByTitle (title) {
  for (var x = 0; x < Movies.length; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < Movies[x].length; y++) {
  if (title === Movies[x][y].title) {
    return Movies[x];
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
};

function getAverageDuration () {
  var totalMovies = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Movies.length; i++) {
  totalMovies.push[i];
}
  var durationTotal = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x < Movies.length; x++) {
      durationTotal += (Movies[x][2]) ;
    }

  var totalAvg = (durationTotal / totalMovies.length);
  return totalAvg;
};
```

I appreciate that this might all be completely garbage code, but I'm hoping if someone can show me the light, it might inspire me to keep progressing with coding instead of giving up and continue working in a bar forever

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow, I can take a look in a couple of hours! I think I can see why but need to check!

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming. Let me see if I can come up with something in Vanilla Javascript.

Comment: _"Please be certain to use only syntax and techniques covered in the assigned freeCodeCamp courses. "_: this question will be difficult to answer due to this constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear about your setback. Here's the code, let me know if you have questions:

```
class Movie {
    constructor(title, duration, quote) {
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    isLongerThan(other) {
        return this.duration > other.duration;
    }

    logQuote() {
        console.log(this.quote);
    }
}

function createMovie(title, duration, quote) {
    return new Movie(title, duration, quote);
}

function getMovieByTitle(movies, title) {
    for (let m of movies)
        if (m.title === title)
            return m;
}

function getAverageDuration(movies) {
    let total = 0;

    for (let m of movies)
        total += m.duration;

    return total / movies.length;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest version without using any class, and functions that you are yet to familiarize. I have written a simple solution with loops. You can write the same thing using `class` and `map` functions as given in other answers.

```
let movies = [];

/**
 * Creates a new movie object and adds the object to
 * the movies array.
 * 
 * Returns the newly created movies object.
 */
function createMovie(title, duration, quote) {

    let movie = {
        title: title,
        duration: duration,
        quote: quote,
        isLongerThan: function (other_movie) {            
            return this.duration > other_movie.duration;
        },
        logQuote: function () {
            console.log(this.quote);
        }
    }
    movies.push(movie);

    return movie;
}

/**
 * Searches the movies array for matching title and returns 
 * the movie object if a match is found. Returns "undefined"
 * if no atch is found.
 * 
 * @param string title 
 */
function getMovieByTitle(title) {
    for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        let movie = movies[i];

        if (movie.title === title) {
            return movie;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Gets the average duration of all the movies using a simple
 * for loop.
 */
function getAverageDuration() {

    let total_duration = 0;
    let average_duration = 0;

    if (movies.length > 0) {
        // Iterate through the movies, if movies array
        // is not empty. If we don't do this check, the average
        // duration could result in an NaN result (division by 0).
        for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
            let movie = movies[i];

            total_duration += isNan(movie.duration) ? 0 : movie.duration;
        }
        // Rounds the average to two decimal places.
        average_duration = (total_duration / movies.length).toFixed(2);
    }
    return average_duration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sucks to be stuck on a piece of code. We've all been there.
This is how I would execute your assignment.

And just like @georg. If you have any questions, please let us know.

```
class Movie {

    constructor(title, duration, quote) {
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    isLongerThan(movie) {
        return this.movie.duration > movie.duration;
    }

    logQuote() {
        console.log(this.quote);
    }

}

const movies = [];

function createMovie(title, duration, quote) {
    let movie = new Movie(title, duration, quote);
    movies.push(movie);
}

function getMovieByTitle(title) {
    return movies.find(movie => movie.title === title);
}

function getAverageDuration() {
    return movies.reduce(accumulator, movie => {
        return accumulator + movie.duration;
    }, 0) / movies.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sux spending money on education and not getting it approved :/. Hope you don't give up!
I tried to replicate your enviroment. It stands in your task you should not use other stuff you haven't learned yet. I used a more modern for-loop than you...

```js
var movies = [];

// Task 1:
function createMovie(title, duration, quote) {
    // Something missing
    if (!title || !duration || !quote) {
        console.error('Missing parameter.');

        return null;
    }
    // Convert type
    if (typeof duration === 'string') {
        duration = Number(duration);
    }
    // Check type
    if (typeof title !== 'string' || typeof duration !== 'number' || typeof quote !== 'string') {
        console.error('Parameter type incorrect.');

        return null;
    }

    return {
        title,
        duration,
        quote,
        methods: {
            isLongerThan: (movie) => {
                if (movie && typeof movie === 'object' && duration > movie.duration) { return true; }
                return false;
            },
            logQuote: () => {
                console.log('Quote:', quote);
            }
        }
    };
}

// Task 2: Add movies
movies.push(createMovie('Star Wars', 121, 'If there\'s a bright center to the universe, you\'re on the planet that it\'s farthest from.'));
movies.push(createMovie('Pulp Fiction', 154, 'Do you know what they call a Quarter Pounder with Cheese in France?'));
movies.push(createMovie('Dirty Dancing', 100, 'Nobody puts Baby in a corner.'));
movies.push(createMovie('Forrest Gump', 142, 'Life is like a box of chocolates.'));
movies.push(createMovie('The Wizard of Oz', 101, 'Lions and tigers and bears, oh my!'));
movies.push(createMovie('Cabaret', 124, 'Life is a cabaret, old chum, so come to the cabaret.'));

// Task 3:
function getMovieByTitle(title) {
    // Should maybe be async
    if (title && typeof title === 'string') {
        for (let movie of movies) {
            if (movie.title.toLocaleLowerCase() === title.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                return movie;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
function getAverageDuration() {
    // Should maybe be async
    let combinedDurations = 0;

    for (let movie of movies) {
        combinedDurations += movie.duration;
    }

    return (combinedDurations / movies.length);
}

//
// Display some results
var movie0 = document.getElementById('movie0');
var movie0Compared = document.getElementById('movie0-compared');

movie0.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(movies[0], undefined, 2) + '</pre>';
movie0Compared.innerHTML = 'Is Movie 0 longer than Movie 1? <b>' + movies[0].methods.isLongerThan(movies[1]) + '</b>';

movies[0].methods.logQuote();
console.log('Pulp Fiction:', getMovieByTitle('pulp fiction').duration, 'min');
console.log('Average duration:', getAverageDuration().toFixed(0), 'min');
```

```html
<h1>Results for: Movie0</h1>

<div id="movie0"></div>
<div id="movie0-compared"></div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```